# How to get the count of distinct objects in a List<Objects>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, class

I have a C# List of class object like this:

```
{
  { id=1, date=04-07-2014 }
  { id=1, date=05-07-2015 }
  { id=2, date=05-05-2014 }
  { id=3, date=12-06-2014 }
  { id=4, date=12-07-2014 }
  { id=2, date=11-07-2014 }
}
```

How is it possible to find the count of each of the distinct 'id's in the List, which belong to the month July. The date is stored as 'dd-MM-yyyy'.

Comment: What is the type of `date` is it string or `DateTime`. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx where IEnumerable#Distinct is described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your records first based on Month using `date.Month` and later for each group you have to group by `Ids` and then select each `Id` and its count in a Dictionary like:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(r => r.date.Month)
            .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Month = grp.Key,
                    IdsCount = grp.GroupBy(r => r.id)
                                    .ToDictionary(subGroup => subGroup.Key, 
                                                  subGroup => subGroup.Count()),
                });
```

if your date is a string format `"yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss"` then group like:

```
list.GroupBy(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.date, "yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
```

EDIT:

To get those values back:

```
foreach (var month in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("For the month of: {0}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month.Month));
    foreach (var id in month.IdsCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} , Count: {1}", id.Key, id.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, Month is not being recognized. My date is in this format: 2014-12-07T00:00:00 (yyyy-dd-MMThh:mm:ss).

Comment: @Roshan, Well you said in your comments that it is a `DateTime` type object, Why are you storing it as a string in first place. However you can parse the Date string to `DateTime` and then use Month property. Use `DateTime.ParseExact(r.date, "yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)`

Comment: Thanks Habib. Sorry for that, actually, the web api, I am calling for getting the List is storing the date i that format. But, how o I access the Dictionary outside var query?

Comment: @Roshan, something like `query.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Month = 7).IdsCount` , *(suppose you want to access ids for month of july)*

Comment: I would like to get the id's and the count.

Comment: @Roshan, Just edited the answer with the way to get ids for each month and their count. Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, thanks Habib. This is what I wanted. Thank You.
Can I ask a question related to this? Suppose, the List contains only distinct id's, how can we load the id and date into a Dictionary.